# SAS : Compare Array Values to Variable Values

Tags: arrays, variables, sas

I have a strange problematic, it try to solve with an array. Here's the thing :
i have this dataset  :

[image: Have]

Variable Code is an id for a type of expense. Amount is the amount of the expense.
What i'ld like to do is create a column for each code and put the amount of the expense in it.

[image: Want]

I tried different things to get this results with array like :

```
      data Want;
    
        set Have;
 
        array _Code{*} 3MC 7MC 7GI 7GT;
        do i = 1 to dim (_Code); 
        if code=_Code{i} then _Code{i}=Amount ; 
        end; 

run;
```

Does anyone have an idea how i can fix this ?
Thanks !

Comment: Why go to the trouble to make a photograph to show 10 values. Please post text as text not photographs.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a silly structure to create, but PROC TRANSPOSE can do it.

```
data have;
  input name :$32. value ;
cards;
3MC 12.5
7MC 23
;

proc transpose data=have out=want(drop=_name_);
  by name value;
  id name;
  var value;
run;
```

Results

```
Obs    name    value    _3MC    _7MC

 1     3MC      12.5    12.5      .
 2     7MC      23.0      .      23
```

Notice how SAS had to modify your character variable's values to make them into names that could be used as variable names.  SAS names cannot start with a digit.  Only a letter or an underscore.

Comment: Can also add `idlabel code;` statement to the PROC TRANSPOSE step

Comment: Yeah, it's not the smartest data structure, but that what i needed. 
Thanks for your answer !